# Generating Controller, Model, Migration and View in GUI on Laravel

Tags: laravel

Is there any quick method for making `Controller`, `Model`, `View`, `Migration` (Including `Relation`, `Data Type`, `Column`, `Key`) in `GUI` mode. Just now, i only using `CLI`, Just Wondering that i could use that kind of GUI in `Laravel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install this generator from [infyom](http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/).

It has CLI generator for complete CRUD and you can install a GUI interface.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help